I would like to define the bullet signs on a list in a Word file using C# and the namespace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
I'm implementing a C#-program that add paragraph in a word file using C# and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace. I would like to add theparagraph in form of a list and define a bullet sign.
I tried the following code to define the bullet sign "!",but i get the error : This process is not available for ListTemplate objects in a ListCatalogue.
  class WordParagraph
    {
     static void Main (string[] args)
      {
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add();
        Word.Paragraph paragraph = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
        paragraph.Range.Text = "Listelement";
        paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
        Word.ListGallery listGallery = wordApp.ListGalleries[Word.WdListGalleryType.wdBulletGallery];
        Word.ListTemplate listTemplate = listGallery.ListTemplates.Add(OutlineNumbered: true);
        listTemplate.ListLevels[1].NumberFormat = "!";
paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(listTemplate, ContinuePreviousList:              false, ApplyTo: Word.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:      Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior);
    wordApp.Quit;
}
}


Does this answer your question? Creating a multi-level bullet list with Word.Interop
